How to get text only debug using devel 5.3.1
I've just upgraded devel to version 5.3.1 and it seems like the devel_dumper setting to just write text to /tmp/drupal_debug.txt has gone away.
How can I use devel_debug() in a way that I can work with the output outside of a browser?

Which was the prior version of Devel you had installed? Knowing that information would help greatly to get an answer.

I went from 5.1.2 to 5.3.1. Here is the MR that removed the functionality: https://gitlab.com/drupalspoons/devel/-/merge_requests/190. For now I've made my own copy of that plugin but I'd still like to know what the new way of doing things is.
